# How to enable Logback-access in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I'm trying to enable logback-access in a spring boot app to log all http requests that hit the application.

I've tried implementing this using: https://github.com/akihyro/logback-access-spring-boot-starter

Adding the XML file shown in the example doesn't do anything, is there anything more that needs to be added to enable?

Any other suggestions to achieve the same result would be welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

you still need to wire a bean to your application...like this code snippet wires the filter to your application:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

    // ... your other methods here

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);

        return filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a Logback access logging. This is a Spring web filter. What if you have your Rest rejected before it reaches Spring classes? This won't be logged by this filter.

Comment: @Zon the javadoc for the `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` literally says “Simple request logging filter that writes the request URI (and optionally the query string) to the Commons Log.” it’s not restricted to a certain logging framework but you can just add logback dependency which i presume OP did already.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure you are talking about the logback logger for SpringBoot. If I am not wrong, this is how you can do this

a. Add the dependency in your POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

b. Now there are may ways you can ask spring to configure logback. For example

## In the application.properties file

## In the logback.xml file

The advantage of using logback.xml file is that, you might have different xml file for different build profile. But in the application.properties, you don’t have this freedom.

Sample entries in the application.properties file from one of my project

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web = INFO
logging.level.com.company.app = DEBUG
#logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.file=logs/spring-boot-logging.log
## Hibernate Logging
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG
```

If you are using XML, configuration probably will look like this

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.memorynotfound" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <configuration scan="true"/>
</configuration>
```

I recommend you to do some Googling for better understating.

Good luck!